# Trying to convert a nasty logarithm into an exponential

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

I have the following equation that I must express in terms of $r$:

$$\Delta V = \frac{\lambda}{2 \pi \epsilon_0} \ln(\frac{r}{R})$$

This is a pretty tough one. I am not sure how to get the r out of the logarithm. I have tried to express the logarithm as $\ln(r) - \ln(R)$, but I am not sure where to go from there, or where the coefficient should go. I know that $\Delta V$ goes up in the exponent...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First solve for $\ln\left(\frac{r}{R}\right)$. We get 
$$\ln\left(\frac{r}{R}\right)=\frac{2\pi\epsilon_0 \Delta V}{\lambda}.$$
Now take the exponential of both sides, and it's nearly over.

**Remark:** Under other circumstances, your observation that $\ln\left(\frac{r}{R}\right)=\ln r-\ln R$ would be useful. Here it *can* be used, but there are quicker ways.

Comment: Inside the natural log function would be on the left hand side, and the coefficient of the messy lambda business on the right would be $e$, but I am not sure what to do about the fact that the expression inside the natural log function is a ratio.

Comment: oh, i see it now!

Comment: $\frac{r}{R} = e^{\frac{2 \pi \epsilon_0\Delta V}{\lambda}} \rightarrow r = Re^{\frac{2 \pi \epsilon_0 \Delta V}{\lambda}}$

Comment: Yes, you got it.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. For some reason I was confused about the ratio inside the natural logarithm, i.e. $\frac{r}{R}$. But I was just over-thinking it, perhaps. Thanks again, Mr. Nicolas.

Comment: You are welcome. If you use the fraction rule you mentioned, we get $\ln r=\ln R+e^{a/\lambda}$. when we exponentiate we get $r=e^{\ln R}e^{a/\lambda}$. Then you can replace $e^{\ln R}$ by $R$, getting the same thing as you got. Just a little longer.